# Yii2 - Why is an image not shown on subpages

Tags: yii2

In layouts\main.php I added an image which should be shown on every page at the same place (header). I added following code in main.php (layout):

```
...
<div class="intl">
<a href="http://www.example.org" target="_blank>
<img src="../files/wsk/design/intl.png" alt="Text" align="right"> </img>
</a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.example.org" target="_blank">International</a>
<div>
...
```

The image is shown on the homepage but not on subpages like About or Contact as shown on the pictures attached. Would be glad if anybody could tell me why.

[image: Yii2 - Homepage]
[image: Yii2 - AboutPage]

Comment: (I removed the "Solved" from your title. If one of the answers helped you out, you can accept it by clicking the "check" mark. That is enough indication for everyone an acceptable solution has been found. If you found out the answer by yourself and it's not in the given answers, you are free to add an answer of your own.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you used related path for image (with `..`).

It's recommended to place such images in web accesible directory (`web`), in subfolder `images` for example, then access it like that: `/images/design/your-image-name.jpg`.

If your image is outside of web accessible directory, alternatively you can use assets to publish it there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be to do with using the relative URL in your img tag. Try this:

```
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>files/wsk/design/intl.png" alt="Text" align="right">
```

If that still doesn't work, check your baseUrl in your configuration is correctly pointing to the folder with your index.php to make sure your URLs are all resolving properly.

Answer (score 0):

In your layouts/main add Html helper

```
<?=
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>
```

Now you can display the image by

```
<?= Html::img('path/to/your/imagefile', ['alt' => 'text', 'height' => '28', 'width' => '112']) ?>
```

or you can create a uploads folder in the root of the project and create an alias for it. That will make your job easy for image display in all the pages. You can use the below code to display an image if alias is set for uploads folder

```
<?= Html::img('@uploads/imagefile', ['alt' => 'text', 'height' => '28', 'width' => '112']) ?>
```